# How Google indexes sites with JavaScript-loaded content?

Tags: javascript, indexing

I wonder, is Google index and rate sites with dynamically loaded content as good as sites with static content? For example, what about site, where all the layout and elements are created by JavaScript and all the content is Ajax-loaded.

Comment: Google loads links starting with `#!/`. Google even has a manual for this but I can't find it right now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do some extra work but is perfectly possible to generate indexable ajax based websites.

Main thing you have to do is make sure that any url that uses a `#!hash` to determine what to view, also has a `?_escaped_fragment_=` url that generates the exact same content.

For more (and likely more understandable) information look at https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: Great! So, before I dive into article, say, is it possible to build fully JavaScript-built web site (all the elements and content is dynamically loaded) and make it good-indexable as simple HTML web-site?

Answer (score 1):

google's crawler now does index content that is generated from javascript. You can see this working at http://www.adynamicjssite.com/ and by googling for site:adynamicjssite.com (the snippet google renders comes from content that's stored in javascript).

Note that bing and others do not yet support running javascript while spidering your site.

Answer (score 0):

No. Crawlers do not scrape dynamically generated content.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769

> Use a text browser such as Lynx to
>   examine your site, because most search
>   engine spiders see your site much as
>   Lynx would. If fancy features such as
>   JavaScript, cookies, session IDs,
>   frames, DHTML, or Flash keep you from
>   seeing all of your site in a text
>   browser, then search engine spiders
>   may have trouble crawling your site.

If you view your page source (CTRL+U in Firefox), you'll see everything the web crawler sees.

Comment: So, only page source take part in crawling, not generated after?

Comment: Not entirely true, a lot of ajax generated sites are indexed quite well on google

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Crawlme](https://github.com/OptimalBits/Crawlme) to automatically make your web app pages indexable by google.